# storing google maps marker information in a database

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am creating a website with Google App Engine using Python for the back end and I am trying to give the website some google maps functionality.

I would like to have it so that users can submit a marker onto the map and then that marker's GPS coords will be stored in a database along with some other text info and I am able to do all of this but I am not sure how to put all of these markers with their respective infowindows back out onto a map.  I would imagine I could do some sort of for loop but I can't find what the javascript should be to place them all.  And it is going to be over 1000 markers and more being added every couple days so just putting them on a map one by one isn't really an option.

Comment: I think you just need to start with some simple Maps API tutorials and get used to setting markers from a database. I'd also check out markerclusterer for handling large numbers of markers.

Answer (score 1):

See the [articles section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/), there are a number of articles about using PHP/mySQL, the concepts of which should be applicable to your system.

This one probably covers what you need:
[Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)

Shows how to use PHP/MySQL and the Google Maps API v3 to create a map that polls data from a database and shows as markers.